# Cisco Webex app on Android 6.0.1 phone

Tags: applications, google-play-store, 6.0-marshmallow

My android phone [spec](http://phonedb.net/index.php?m=device&id=10053&c=huawei_gr5_lte_kii-l05) says:

1) Dimensions are 3.00x5.96x0.32 inches

2) Display Resolution - Horizontal and vertical resolution of the primary display - 1080x1920

---

Installed Cisco webex app from Playstore. Phone connected with WIFI access point.

---

But, the Cisco webex meetings [guide](https://support.webex.com/pdf/Cisco_WebEx_Meetings_Android_gsg_v3_0.pdf) says:

Your tablet must meet one of the following requirements:

- Screen size 7.1 inches or larger and Android 3.0 or later
- Screen width 6000 dp or larger and Android 3.2 or later

---

I could not test the webex link that will be used for my interview, next week, until the host is available.

---

Does this phone [spec](http://phonedb.net/index.php?m=device&id=10053&c=huawei_gr5_lte_kii-l05) support Cisco webex audio/video call?Dimensions are 3.00x5.96x0.32 inches

Answer (score 0):

Only one device fits the dimensions you've shared, and that's the Huawei GR5, which is a phablet with screen size of 5.5 inches, which doesn't fit any of the requirements. But even if it's not that specific model, it's not physically possible to have a bigger screen fit in those dimensions. So even if you're not talking about the Huawei GR5, your device still doesn't meet Cisco's requirements.

Comment: Then how come, users use phone for webex meetings? I don't think average dimension of a phone is bigger than the given in query? Why does my phone not fit the requirement?

Comment: @overexchange First requirement: Screen size 7.1 inches or lager - your phone has a screen size of 5.5 inches. 5.5 < 7.1, therefor, the phone doesn't meet the first requirement. Second requirement: Screen width 6000 dp or larger - your phone width is 360dp (1080x1920 in 5.5 inches is xxhdpi, whch means your width in dp is (1080 / (0.00625 * 480 )) = 360dp). 360 < 6000. This is why your phone does not fit the requirements :)

Comment: Whatever, I am selected